# Jboss Quartz Subsystem

Tags: jboss7.x, quartz-scheduler, redhat, subsystem

I am running Jboss on domain mode with some servers distributed. The problem presented itself as the need to update quartz max threads. I searched and understood that I can change this value at quartz.properties and get the output I want. My question is, is there anyway that allows me to update max threads without stopping the servers ? Maybe a subsystem at domain.xml level. Are you aware of something that can do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Quartz subsystem therefore the host controller can't manage quartz on the domain servers. If the `quartz.properties` supports some kind of system property expressions, e.g. `${some.key:default}`, then you could use [system properties](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/General+configuration+concepts#Generalconfigurationconcepts-SystemProperties).

Comment: Great suggestion ! Up and running, now will try to find some way to hot reload the properties to be able to change properties without restart ! Thank you